# Shouldn't the compiler warn me that class does not respond to copyWithZone?

Tags: objective-c

Assume that in some class interface I declare a property with the "copy" attribute which is an instance of another class which *does not* implement "-copyWithZone". Say for instance

```
@interface Dog: NSObject
@property (assign) int i;
@end

@interface Pets: NSObject
@property (copy) Dog *myDog;
@end
```

then somewhere I do

```
Pets *myPets = [[Pets alloc] init];
Dog *uglyDog = [[Dog alloc] init];
myPets.myDog = uglyDog;
```

What happens is that at runtime I get an exception like "-[Dog copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector..." which I undestand perfectly.

But shouldn't the compiler warn me about this? (It didn't).

Comment: It would if you declared @interface Dog:NSObject <NSCopying>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler should be able to work that out in the case that it synthesizes the copy accessor. I would open a radar requesting a warning there.

It's important to note that the warning should only be for a automatically synthesized copy accessor referencing a non-NSCopying class. The compiler shouldn't warn if you override the accessor yourself. I have had many classes with `copy` properties that did not conform to `NSCopying`; I just implement copying semantics in the setter. The `copy` in that case is documentation for the caller, not an instruction to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

@property modifiers are used to specify (or modify) the behaviour of instance variables. Objective-C is a dynamic language so it evaluates majority of typings at runtime. The copy modifier isn't other than sending a copy message to your object and because messages are dispatched at runtime you won't get any sort of error until the message reaches the messaged object which doesn't respond to its selector.
You will get a warning from the compiler only if you specify you want your class to conform to NSCopying protocol by:

```
 @interface MyClass : Superclass <NSCopying>
```

and than you don't implement the required methods. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I was assuming that I ask the compiler to synthesize the setter for myDog (thanks @Rob for pointing this out). Hence the compiler (morally) produces a code that sends the "copy" (or "copyWithZone:') message to myDog. I thought it could be a good idea to give a "may not respond" kind of warning. I was just wondering if there might be reasons _not_ to issue this warning, but I don't see them.